# WaterMark in textbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, placeholder, watermark

This is an easy question but i am not able to achieve the result. i want align search icon right side within the textblock and text on the left side
here is my style for textbox

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource waterMark}" Margin="0 20 0 0"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>

<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkBackground" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkForeground" Color="LightSteelBlue" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkBorder" Color="Indigo" />

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
    <local:TextInputToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TextInputToVisibilityConverter" />


    <Style x:Key="waterMark" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="enter your text here">
                                          <Image Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Source="/Resources/search.ico" Width="10" Height="10"></Image>
                                <TextBlock.Visibility>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextInputToVisibilityConverter}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="InputText" Path="Text.IsEmpty"></Binding>
                                        <Binding ElementName="InputText" Path="IsFocused"></Binding>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </TextBlock.Visibility>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBox x:Name="InputText" Background="Transparent"></TextBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've added a Grid for the textblock and the image and it should work now:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextInputToVisibilityConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="InputText" Path="Text.IsEmty"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="InputText" Path="IsFocused"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Grid.Visibility>
            <TextBlock Text="enter your text here" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Source="/Resources/search.ico" Width="10" Height="10"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="InputText" Background="Transparent"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```